# Question about the half angle of sensitivity of a photodiode

Tags: diodes, sensor

I am currently designing a sensor array for the front-end of a line following robot. The transducers of that array will be SFH213 photodiodes, which I have purchased for their linear response to visible light and their low angle of half-sensitivity, which is labelled as +/- 10 degrees. I am trying to design the array so that they are sensitive to an area in front of them with a diameter of about 5mm (about 20 mm^2.)

Is the angle of half sensitivity measured from the very end of the 9mm long photodiode, or is it taken from the silicon chip in the diode itself? As you can imagine, when working with such short distances this makes a big difference in the final performance.

Comment: The half-angle is probably measured from a "far" distance, so the exact point isn't that relevant. In general, the point where the angle is measured is the "entrance pupil", which for a crude lens like this, is probably one radius from the front. At very close distances, the formulas may not work well, your best bet it to make some measurements yourself. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_view

Comment: The people at Physics SE can answer better, although their answer may be highly technical. You will get a better response at their site if you make your question stand-alone (include a figure describing the problem).

Comment: This is **not** a physics problem.  It is a question of the definitions used in a datasheet, not a generic "assume a spherical chicken in a vacuum" question.  This is technical and specific to a particular component.

Comment: If you want a "fixed" angle, you can use "tubes" in front of the LEDs to guide the light ...

Comment: Those diodes have an integrated lens which sets their angular field of view. If you need a different field of view, you could use diodes without a lens and then mount your own lens in front of it. By picking the focal length you can make the field of view whatever you want.

Comment: A link to the data sheet you're asking about would be helpful.